# Correctly submit triplets to a BERT model with triplet loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, bert-language-model

I'm working on a model consisting in taking the elements of a triplet (consisting in an anchor, a positive example and a negative example), pass them through a BERT model and use them to calculate the triplet loss. Here is the code I have for the moment:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, TFDistilBertModel
from tensorflow import keras

model_name = "distilbert-base-multilingual-cased"
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

## retrieve data that finally is a data frame with 3 columns (anchor, positive, negative):
test_data = test_data[['anchor', 'match', 'non_match']]
sample_size = int(0.8 * len(test_data))
train, validation = test[:sample_size], test[sample_size:]

def triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    """ ignore y_true
    """
    anchor = y_pred[:, :VECTOR_SIZE]
    positive = y_pred[:, VECTOR_SIZE:2*VECTOR_SIZE]
    negative = y_pred[:, 2*VECTOR_SIZE:]
    pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), 1) 
    neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), 1)
    basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), 0.1)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0), 0)
    return loss

def create_model(model):
    input_anchor = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_length,), name='input_anchor', dtype='int32')
    input_positive = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_length,), name='input_positive', dtype='int32')
    input_negative = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_length,), name='input_negative', dtype='int32')
    anchor_output = model(input_anchor)[0]
    positive_output = model(input_positive)[0]
    negative_output = model(input_negative)[0]
    merged_output = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([anchor_output, positive_output, negative_output])
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_anchor, input_positive, input_negative], outputs=merged_output) 
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss = triplet_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Now I can create the model:

```
triplet_model = create_model(model)
triplet_model.summary()

Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_anchor (InputLayer)      [(None, 64)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_positive (InputLayer)    [(None, 64)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_negative (InputLayer)    [(None, 64)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 tf_distil_bert_model (TFDistil  TFBaseModelOutput(l  134734080  ['input_anchor[0][0]',           
 BertModel)                     ast_hidden_state=(N               'input_positive[0][0]',         
                                one, 64, 768),                    'input_negative[0][0]']         
                                 hidden_states=None                                               
                                , attentions=None)                                                
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)      (None, 64, 2304)     0           ['tf_distil_bert_model[0][0]',   
                                                                  'tf_distil_bert_model[1][0]',   
                                                                  'tf_distil_bert_model[2][0]']   
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 134,734,080
Trainable params: 134,734,080
Non-trainable params: 0
```

When I try to fit the model:

```
history = triplet_model.fit(
    x=[train['anchor'], train['match'], train['non_match']],
    y=None,
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=5,
    steps_per_epoch=2
)
```

it returns me this error:

```
ValueError: Target data is missing. Your model was compiled with loss=<function triplet_loss at 0x7f6161a1f9a0>, and therefore expects target data to be provided in `fit()
```

What am I missing?? As far as i know theres no need to provide y when your loss function is a triplet loss

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I am curious why you are concatenating the output.  Generally speaking, triplet loss works on the principle (often cosine similarity) of moving the "true" value closer to the anchor and moving the far value further away.  This difference in the similarity is where the "margin" comes into play specifically for tuning. In very simplistic terms the distance between an anchor and positive is > Margin + distance between the anchor and negative. There is more to do but I would examine the concatenation step and loss calculation. Using tf cosine similarity will also speed your model up

Comment: And to address your statement:  I would pass the anchor as X and the Y to be a zipped tuple of pos/neg pairs, then process the pairs.